# Clion WSL tool chain error after upgrade to Ubuntu20.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 (version 1909, build 18363.836), CLion 2020.1. Recently I upgrade my wsl from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I run the script Jet Brains provided (https://github.com/JetBrains/clion-wsl/blob/master/ubuntu_setup_env.sh), but I got these errors when CLion are loading my projects:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /mnt/d/Projects/COMP26120
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:185 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:212 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:210 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:80 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:73 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/Projects/COMP26120/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/Projects/COMP26120/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Failed to reload]
```

In CLion settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains, I also got this warning:
[CLion Toolchains warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Cru.png)

Everything was fine when I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, What caused this problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share output from toolchain page if you click on more link from warning message?